# How can I style texarea with some bold italic code functions?

Tags: javascript, css, styles, textarea

I am gonna style my textarea input like this image?
What should I do.

[image: That is how actually my textare should looks like]

Comment: Have you tried searching for something like 'how do I add a text editor to an HTML textarea'?

Comment: Yes but could not found anything

Comment: There's loads about adding editors, like tinymce/CKeditor etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So for the there are lots of js libraries out there.

One of them and I think the best of them is CKeditor.js.

You can find it [here](https://ckeditor.com/docs/ckeditor5/latest/builds/guides/quick-start.html) :)